# SQL select only one row when there are two max (XXX)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, max

I have a 'game' table that contains columns of ID, Name, Score, Time. There are total 10 rows in the table which stores the top 10 record of a game. My program is when a user is able to enter top 10, the row with max(time) will be deleted:

```
delete from game  where time =  (select x.del_time from (select max(time) as del_time from game) x)"
```

However, when there are more than 1 row with the same max(time), it will delete both rows. So My question is how to delete just 1 row? Just like if the max time are the same, get the max score, and if max score are also the same, get the max ID (as ID is auto increment, it will not be the same). Thank you!!

Comment: Try to use " LIMIT 1" at the end of query

Comment: Also note that your original query can be done with one subquery and no aliasing, which will make it a lot simpler: `delete from game where time = (select max(time) from game)`.

Comment: @EdGibbs It shows error "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'game' for update in FROM clause" anyway thanks!

Comment: @liding It works! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that Tony - I forgot that MySQL doesn't like the direct subquery of the table it's deleting.

Comment: Never mind, thanks for your advice =]

Comment: @TonyCheok I don't get it, how can this work? `MAX(time)` returns *always* one record, no matter how many share the same maximum time value.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I don't know why... It really returns more than one record.

Comment: @TonyCheok The `SELECT` clause returns exactly one record, whereas the `WHERE` clause of the `DELETE` statement returns more than one.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos this query delete more than one record because we have 'where' part such as 'time = ...'. In that case we can get from 0 to n rows from table 'game'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete by `ID`:

```
DELETE FROM game
WHERE id = (SELECT id 
            FROM (
              SELECT id 
              FROM game
              WHERE `time` = (SELECT MAX(`time`) FROM game)
              ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC
              LIMIT 1) AS x)
```

The above query will delete from record having the maximum `time` value. In case there are more than one such rows, then it will pick the one having the maximum `score` value. In case of a `score` tie, then it will pick the one having the maximum `id` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca1fc/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from game  where time =  (select x.del_time from (select max(time) as del_time from game LIMIT 1) x)"
```

Comment: You have the `LIMIT 1` on the `select max(time)...` query, which only returns one row to begin with.

Comment: The LIMIT 1 should be put at the end.  

delete from game  where time =  (select x.del_time from (select max(time) as del_time from game) x)LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from game  where time =  (select x.del_time from (select max(time) as del_time from game LIMIT 1) x) "
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete it by using `limit 1` at the end of the query or by `id`.